# libfaketime and java on RHEL 5 / RHEL 6

Tags: java, linux, time, rhel

In order to test java-code with date / time set into the past or future I want to try libfaketime (currently we just adjust the system clock, but it causes much trouble like non working kerberos, etc).

I try with this small test program:

```
$ cat time.java
import java.util.*;

class TimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] s) {

        long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
        java.util.Date date = cal.getTime();

        System.out.println("Date: " + date);
    }
}
```

And executes this:

```
LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.6.18 LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d" /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.7_64/bin/java TimeTest
Invalid clock_id for clock_gettime: -172402[root@myhost ~]#
```

But as you can see I just get an error message.
The test is performed on a RHEL 6.5 server, kernel 2.6.32-431 and
libfaketime 0.9.6

Do you have any suggestions how I can solve this? I'm also interested in hearing your experiences with libfaketime and java on RHEL.

I have also reported this issue at: https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/issues

Best reagards,

Erling

Answer (score 0):

I've observed this incorrect behaviour as well in IBM JVM 1.7.0 while in Oracle JVM 1.6.0 this works as expected. 
The explanation is that IBM JVM apparatently has an internal bug which manifests by calling [clock_gettime](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/18329997/) system call with incorrect clock_id parameter (random negative value).
The workaround (not a fix) is to modify [libfaketime.c](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/blob/master/src/libfaketime.c) to reset the clock_id to valid value in fake_clock_gettime function.

```
case FT_START_AT: /* User-specified offset */
  if (user_per_tick_inc_set)
  {
    /* increment time with every time() call*/
    next_time(tp, &user_per_tick_inc);
  }
  else
  { 
    if (clk_id < 0) { // jvm calls clock_gettime() with invalid random negative clock_id value
        clk_id = CLOCK_REALTIME;
    }

    switch (clk_id)
    // the rest is the same
```

This will prevent the libfaketime.so.1 library from existing on error you are observing

```
 printf("\nInvalid clock_id for clock_gettime: %d", clk_id);
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Please note this workaround has a drawback that in case JVM is incorrectly asking system for invalid clockid, we will assume valid clockid which may be not what application expects.